# Format number as money

Tags: c#, string, format

How do I format a number to look like this: 9,000
my database field is in money data type, when I pull it up I see it like this: 9000.0000 
that don't look right to me (I would like it to look like a real money format)

Answer (score 24):

While you could call string.format, I think it's easier to just call [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b22a4x2.aspx) on it.

```
decimal money = 9000m;
string formattedMoney = money.ToString("C");
```

Answer (score 11):

```
decimal money = 1000;
Response.Write(string.Format("{0:C}", money));
```

The above is an example in C#.

Comment: Response.Write(string.Format("{0:C}", money)) would also be the equivalent in VB .NET since its really the framework doing the formatting, not the language

Comment: "{0:C0}" is handy too as it adds thousand separators

Answer (score 6):

Thought I'd add a C# 6 option with interpolated strings:

```
decimal money = 9000m;
string formatted = $"{money:C}";
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to do a "formatting" function (in whatever language you're using) that will return the data in a currency format. Another answer already describes the code in C#. Here's vbscript:

```
Dim Amount
Amount = 2000
Response.Write(FormatCurrency(Amount))
```

How your database viewing application reads the data and how it is actually stored in the database may be two different things.