# How to format a money value from an ISOCurrencySymbol in C#

Tags: c#, format, currency

I have created a Money class to save money values in different currencies. The class uses 3 letter ISO symbols to store currency types:

```
public class Money
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way in C# to use this information, say 100.00 USD, and format it as "$100.00"? Only way I know of requires CultureInfo like this:

```
Amount.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

However this does not work with my Money class. Is there another solution? I am open to changing my Money class.

I have searched this site for similar questions (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820913/format-number-as-money)), but couldn't find one that answers the above question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you meant by "this does not work with my Money class"?

Comment: Just because the Money class does not store CultureInfo, it stores only the ISO symbol for the currency.

Answer (score 2):

That's a non-trivial localization issue you have there. Look at these examples [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx):

```
123.456 ("C", en-US) -> $123.46
123.456 ("C", fr-FR) -> 123,46 €
123.456 ("C", ja-JP) -> ¥123
```

How would you display `USD 123.456` to someone in France? `$123.46` or `123,46 $`?

I'd probably stick with displaying it using the 3 letter ISO symbol, although the position of this symbol seems to vary in different countries as well. From [usage guidelines for the **EUR** symbol](http://publications.europa.eu/code/en/en-370303.htm#position):

> In English texts, the ISO code ‘EUR’ is followed by a fixed space and the amount:
>
> ```
> a sum of EUR 30
> ```
>
> NB: The same rule applies in Irish, Latvian and Maltese. In all other official EU languages the order is reversed; the amount is followed by a fixed space and the ISO code ‘EUR’ (or the euro sign in graphics):
>
> ```
> une somme de 30 EUR
> ```

Comment: Hmmm..., I understand what you are saying. I wish there was at least a way to format all currencies for a given local. For example, if running in en-US locale, USD would be shown as $100.00 and Yen would be shown as ¥123.

Answer (score 1):

Check this extension method:

```
public static string FormatCurrency(this decimal amount, string currencyCode)
{
    var culture = (from c in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
            let r = new RegionInfo(c.LCID)
            where r != null
            && r.ISOCurrencySymbol.ToUpper() == currencyCode.ToUpper()
            select c).FirstOrDefault();

    if (culture == null)
        return amount.ToString("0.00");

    return string.Format(culture, "{0:C}", amount);
}
```

Usage:

```
decimal amount = 100;

amount.FormatCurrency("AUD");  //$100.00
amount.FormatCurrency("GBP");  //£100.00
amount.FormatCurrency("EUR");  //100,00 €
amount.FormatCurrency("VND");  //100,00 ₫
amount.FormatCurrency("IRN");  //₹ 100.00
```

This code is from:
http://lukencode.com/2012/05/28/quick-and-dirty-csharp-currency-helper/